# Java Controller not transforming for JSON to entity

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have been unable to receive information from a JSON send through a POST request, that looks something like this:

```
[{
 "idVehicule": 1,
 "vacancies": 3
}]
```

I have a simple controller that tries to get that JSON sent from front, convert it into a testModel:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class testModel {

    @JsonProperty( "idvehicle" )
    private int idvehicle;
    @JsonProperty( "vacancies" )
    private String vacancies;

    public int getIdvehicle() {
        return idvehicle;
    }
    public void setIdvehicle(int idvehicle) {
        this.idvehicle = idvehicle;
    }
    public String getVacancies() {
        return vacancies;
    }
    public void setVacancies(String vacancies) {
        this.vacancies = vacancies;
    }

}
```

And then it just prints one of its values.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/vehicle", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> vehicleTest(@RequestBody testModel testModel){
        System.out.println(testModel.getVacancies());
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);;
    }
```

After trying the method with postman, i keep getting this error:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1472819769941,
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
  "message": "Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of testModel out of START_ARRAY token\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@646345e6; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of testModel out of START_ARRAY token\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@646345e6; line: 1, column: 1]",
  "path": "/vehicle"
}
```

I have also tried changing the JSON and then the problem is that the method is unable to convert it into the enity, making the variable "testModel" always null

```
{"testModel":{"idvehicle":1,"vacancies":3}}
```

Removing the "@RequestBoby" annotation gives the same problem that the paragraph before.

Any ideas that could help me figure out the problem? Thanks

Comment: Send it as plain JSON... `{"idvehicle":1,"vacancies":3}`. Also `idvehicle` will not match `setIdVehicle` it should be `idVehicle` in that case.

Comment: Please place this as an answer so i can accept it, since this is the correct one. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifying `@JsonProperty` as `idvehicle` in your `testModel` so correct the `JSON` you are posting to:

```
 [{
     "idvehicle": 1,
     "vacancies": 3
 }]
```

Next, you are sending the **array of `testModel`** and expecting `testModel` which will of-course will not deserialize.

Either correct the `JSON` you are sending to `{"idvehicle": 1,"vacancies": 3}` or change the `Controller` to accept array of `testModel` as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/vehicle", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> vehicleTest(@RequestBody List<testModel> testModel){

        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, well explained, i decided to change the JSON structure as advice for you and  @M. Deinum , also the problem was that the JSON fields must be identical to the class attributes.

Answer (score 1):

JsonProperty is case sensitive. You need to have the key name exactly same as that in Json. So change it like this and check the spelling also.

```
@JsonProperty( "idVehicule" )
```

Answer (score 0):

You're `POST`ing an array of of `testModel` objects (quick gripe, classnames should start with uppercase letters, so it should be `TestModel`) but your method accepts one `testModel` as `@RequestBody`. Change the method declaration to `public ResponseEntity<String> vehicleTest(@RequestBody List<testModel> testModel){`